# Add a key:value to an existing key in FormData

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, api

I have a form with fields: title, name, and description. I want to submit the form values using the API. I have a jquery code that adds key-value pairs to the FormData variable:

```
formdata.append('description_text', jquery('#description').val())
```

This works fine however, the title and name fields are custom fields, so the JSON structure is:

```
{
    "description_text": "sample description",
    "custom_fields": {
        "name": "Ned",
        "title": "Mr."
    }
}
```

I tried adding:

```
formdata.append('custom_fields', {'title': jquery('#title').val()})
```

and I get the error:

```
[{"field":"custom_fields","message":"Value set is of type String.It should be a/an key/value pair","code":"datatype_mismatch"}]
```

could you please let me know how to sort it out?

Comment: How is the form encoded, URI-encoding? (The default.) Do you want to send JSON as the value of `custom_fields`? How is the server going to process this, by getting a single value from `custom_fields` as parsing it as JSON? Or by getting discrete `custom_fields[name]` and `custom_fields[title]` entries?

Comment: What format does the server expect the data to be sent in? `FormData` is designed for POSTing *multipart/form-data* encoded data. Is that what the server is expecting? Typically servers expecting multipart data will want complex data structures represented using PHP-style naming conventions. You seem to be trying to post some hybrid of multipart data and JSON data. Servers expecting JSON typically expect the whole thing to be a single JSON text. What should the server be given?

Answer (score 1):

You should send `custom_fields` as JSON — that is, your object turned into a JSON string via `stringify`:

```
formdata.append('custom_fields', JSON.stringify({'title': jquery('#title').val()}))
```